# Why does a float value have to be declared twice?

Tags: java

I am confused on why a float value has to be declared in the begging like any other value but then has to be declared right before the value.

Example: 
    Float Z =(float)10.5;

Why cant we declare a float value as;

Example:
    Float Z = 10.5;

http://prntscr.com/a3c7i7

Comment: Java is a strongly-typed language. Implicit casts are possible in weakly-typed languages like c.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `10.5` is a `double` and it cannot be cast to `float` implicitly.
You could define it without the explicit cast as

```
Float z = 10.5f;
```

Answer (score 6):

Floating point literals are `double`s in Java.
To make it a `float` you have to append an `f`.

So that would be:

```
Float Z = 10.5f;
```

Answer (score 4):

Because the same literal is used for representing doubles. 10.5 means `double` which can't fit in a float.

You can express a float literal by appending 'f' or 'F' to the number as follows.

```
float z = 10.5F;
float z = 10.5f;
```

And because float fits in a double the opposite is not true.

```
double d = 10.5F; //works fine
```